# Rails: How to create a link_to that mixes dynamic content with a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I can't figure it out. I'm basically looking to create a link_to that links to a user's profile based on the user's first name but I know you can't just throw in quotes like this:

```
 <%= link_to @food.user.firstname"s profile", user_path(@food.user_id) %>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES,you can as its a string.So this will work without making use of `to_s`..

```
<%= link_to @food.user.firstname.to_s + "'s profile" user_path(@food.user_id) %>
```

add `capitalize` for elegance,check [**api**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) for more...

```
<%= link_to @food.user.firstname.capitalize + "'s profile" user_path(@food.user_id) %>
```

moreover,you just need to reference the `user`,,so `@food.user` will work too.

tested it..works good :)